# Is html5 iframe preferable in Lightning component

Tags: lightning, iframe

We have a requirement to fire an api and show the response using Lightning components. XSLT transformation has to be done on the response to get the actual content. 
As it is not possible to use XSLT with salesforce, we have used html5 iframe in the lightning component.

Is iframe preferable in lightning component ? Plase suggest any alternatives if iframe is not preferable.

Answer (score 1):

The use of an iframe is the recommended approach:

> In those situations, we recommend that you put code that needs access to external resources in a “worker iframe” using Visualforce. The technique looks something like this.

```
<aura:component ...>
    <aura:attribute name="message" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="vfHost" type="String"/>
    <!-- Input field for message "data" -->
    <lightning:input type="text" label="Message:"
        value="{!v.message}"/>
    <lightning:button label="Send to Visualforce"
        onclick="{!c.sendToVF}"/>
    <!-- The Visualforce page to send data to -->
    <iframe aura:id="vfFrame"
     src="{!'https://' + v.vfHost + '/apex/myvfpage'}"/>
</aura:component>
```

XSLT can also be done via MuleSoft, but that may be overkill.

**References**

- [Work Well with JavaScript Unit | Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_vf_tips/lex_dev_lc_vf_tips_javascript)
- [Lightning Security - developer.force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Security)
- [You're into XML? Mule now supports XPath, XSLT and XQuery 3.0 | MuleSoft Blog](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/mule-dev/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/)
- [XSLT Transformations with the XML Module | MuleSoft Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/xml/xml-xslt)
- [Connecting Your APIs with MuleSoft and Salesforce Identity | Developer Force Blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/11/connecting-your-apis-with-mulesoft-and-salesforce-identity.html)